# Colorbox + Form, Submit only working on Enter button (not onclick)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I integrated a popup upon landing on our page http://www.showstye.lu (best seen in an incognito window due to cookie reset). In this popup you have a newsletter signup form which is a copy of the one available in the footer.

I had to duplicate css to adapt to the newsletter popup so that it styled correctly which is fine, I am using Colorbox for the popup itself.

Now, the form itself when I click on the submit button (S'Abonner) it doesn't trigger the submit correctly. I always get a false return telling me to resubmit a new e-mail address.

However, the newsletter form itself works completely fine in the footer and ALSO when I use the keyboard stroke "Enter" instead of clicking on the submit button.

I don't comprehend why one form works in the footer but the identical copy does not (only with Enter keystroke), I looked at the styling/JS/html of the form and it is identical across both.

Any ideas how to resolve this so that the submit button works successfully?

```
<div style='display:none'>
<div id='subscribe_popup'>
<div id="spop_left">
    <div id="spop_top"></div>
    <div id="spop_sign">
        <div class="popbox">
          {% if theme.setting_newsletter %}
                <form id="formNewsletter" action="{{ 'account/newsletter' | url }}" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{ page.key }}" />
                <input type="email" name="email" id="formNewsletterEmail" value="" placeholder="{{ 'E-mail' | t }}"/>
                  <a class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-send" href="#" onclick="$('#formNewsletter').submit(); return false;" title="{{ 'Subscribe' | t }}" {% if shop.language == 'de' %}style="padding: 0px 10px;"{% endif %}><span>{{ 'Subscribe' | t }}</span></a>
              </form>
        </div> {% endif %}
     </div>
     </div>
    <div id="spop_right"></div>


   </div>
   </div> 
  <!-- END subscribe popup-->
```

Here is the JS behind it:

```
    <script> // popup script 
    $("document").ready(function (){ 
   // load the overlay
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
  var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
  var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
  document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
  $.colorbox({width:"553px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
}
  $(".open_popup").colorbox({width:"553px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});

     });
    </script>
```

Comment: I just realised after reading through stackoverflow that my submit button is actually just a url triggering an onclick submit action instead of being an input type=submit...could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok that was it, I was integrating a submit into the hyperlink instead of using a simple inputtype submit, keystroke was obviously working because of how the browser automatically identifies the keystroke enter as a submit!